# Android layout overlapping textfields

Tags: android

I'm new in Android. I just start write my first android app.
When I add two fields and submit button and run apps, its overlaps all fields.
I used "fill_parent" for both text fields. 
Here is the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.icddrb.admin.databaseexample.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="154dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="26dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="154dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="83dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="142dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Can anyone suggest me elaborately what is the issue here. How can I overcome this issues.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what prompted you to use a `ConstrainLayout`, but it appears that you've placed each component's absolute position, with the result that widgets are overlapping.  One quick fix here would be to just use something like a `LinearLayout` where the widgets will more naturally flow from top-to-bottom.  Something like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added any constraints to your views, which is the whole purpose of using ConstraintLayout. Try something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    tools:context="com.icddrb.admin.databaseexample.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```